# Erro de Modelagem asp.net Code First

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estou Tendo erro na hora de Fazer um migration...
Primeiro vou dizer o que quero, para vocês entenderem, tem inconsistência, mas já tentei muito e não consegui resolver.

Quero com essa modelagem dizer que:

1. Um Croqui possui varias Imagens
2. Que um laudo tem um croqui
3. Croqui tem um virtual de laudo porque ele pode acessar o Id laudo através do próprio croqui(pelo menos é assim que acho que funciona)

**Models:**

```
public class Croqui
{


    [Key]
    public int CroquId { get; set; }

    [ ForeignKey("Laudo")]
    public int LaudoId { get; set; }

    public virtual Laudo Laudo { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Imagem> Imagens { get; set; }
}
```

**Imagem**

```
 public class Imagem
{
    public int ImagemId { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
    public String ImagemTipo { get; set; }

    public int CroquiId { get; set; }
    public   virtual Croqui croqui { get; set; }
}
```

**Laudos**

```
 public class Laudo
{
    [Key]
    public int LaudoId { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = ("Ocupante"))]
    public String Ocupante { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = ("Ocupante ID"))]
    public String IdOcupante { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = ("Contato"))]
    public String ContatoOcupante { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = ("UF"))]
    public String Estado { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = ("Município"))]
    public String Municipio { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = ("Nº do Relatório"))]
    public String NumeroRelatorio { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Laudo> Laudos { get; set; }



    public  Croqui Croqui { get; set; }
```

Ai da erro:

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>   Croqui_Laudo_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role >'Croqui_Laudo_Source' in relationship 'Croqui_Laudo'. Because the Dependent >Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the >multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.

Desde ja agradeço a ajuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Models:**

```
public class Croqui
  {
    [Key]
    public int CroquId { get; set; }


    public int LaudoId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("LaudoId")]
    [InverseProperty("Croquis")]
    public virtual Laudo Laudo { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<Imagem> Imagens { get; set; }

   }
```

**Imagem**

```
public class Imagem
{
    public int ImagemId { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
    public String ImagemTipo { get; set; }

    public int CroquiId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CroquiId")]
    [InverseProperty("Imagens")]
    public virtual Croqui croqui { get; set; }
}
```

**Laudos**

Segundo a estrutura do teu model na class Laudo temos um loop

```
public class Laudo
{
    [Key]
    public int LaudoId { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = ("Ocupante"))]
    public String Ocupante { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = ("Ocupante ID"))]
    public String IdOcupante { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = ("Contato"))]
    public String ContatoOcupante { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = ("UF"))]
    public String Estado { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = ("Município"))]
    public String Municipio { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = ("Nº do Relatório"))]
    public String NumeroRelatorio { get; set; }


     public ICollection<Croqui> Croquis { get; set; }

     public int LaudoIdSegundo { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("LaudoIdSegundo")]
    [InverseProperty("Laudos")]
    public virtual Laudo Laudo { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Laudo> Laudos { get; set; }


}
```